# For lib pcapplusplus, why there is no matchSubnet() for ipv6 address

Tags: pcap, libpcap, pcapplusplus

For ipv4 address, I can use matchSubnet() checks whether the address matches a subnet.
But for ipv6, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you [DinoStray](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6851483/dinostray) for implementing this feature in [PcapPlusPlus](https://github.com/seladb/PcapPlusPlus).

Just to wrap this question up with an example on how to use it:

```
// IPv6 address
pcpp::IPv6Address ipv6Address("2607:f0d0:1002:0051:ffff:0000:0000:0004");

// IPv6 subnet
pcpp::IPv6Address subnetIpv6Address("2607:f0d0:1002:0051::");

// Match subnet with 16 bits in a mask - subnet matches
ipv6Address.matchSubnet(subnetIpv6Address, 16);   // True

// Match subnet with 96 bits in a mask - subnet doesn't match
ipv6Address.matchSubnet(subnetIpv6Address, 96);   // False
```

You can see more examples in [PcapPlusPlus tests](https://github.com/seladb/PcapPlusPlus/blob/master/Tests/Pcap%2B%2BTest/Tests/IpMacTests.cpp#L74-L85),

And read more in [`IPv6Address` documentation](https://pcapplusplus.github.io/api-docs/classpcpp_1_1_i_pv6_address.html#ae9015eccc285e177ed21b1099eda1648).

Answer (score 0):

That's a good point, this feature doesn't currently exist in PcapPlusPlus.

I saw you opened a GitHub issue for that: https://github.com/seladb/PcapPlusPlus/issues/444

Let's follow up on it there.